# How set the size of items in listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I use C# with Framework 2.0.

Is it possible to set the size of items in the `ListBox`?

I did not found any property to change size and style of an item.

Comment: As an aside: I'd *very strongly* recommend that you update to a more modern framework. .NET 2.0 went out of *extended* support in April 2016. Goodness knows how many security holes that have been fixed in supported releases are still lingering there.

Comment: @Llama yes is a WinForms

Comment: @JonSkeet If my client use this, it's not my problem.

Comment: If your client is still using a very-much-unsupported platform, I think it's your duty to give them the same advice I gave you. It's one thing to support an unsupported platform for a little while... but .NET 2.0 really is *ancient* at this point, and I'd say that using it is actively dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean C# in windows form application,
List items are text, and you should change the font size.

```cs
    
   listBox1.Font = new Font("any font name like arial", 10); // 10 is the font size
```

or you can set the Listbox font in the `Properties` panel

Comment: Thanks you so much!!!